# Having multiple div with different ids in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

Currently i am working on the XML schema definition using XSD for XHTML. The structure of my XHTML is as follow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="AAA">// (Required, maxnumber = 1)
   <div id="BBB">//  (Required, maxnumber = 1)
      <div id="CCC">...</div>// (Optional)
      <div id="DDD">...</div>// (Optional)
      <div id="EEE">...</div>// (Required, maxnumber = 1)
      <div id="FFF" class="IIII">...</div>// (Required, maxnumber = 1)
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to have check for div tags for following condition for my XHTML

- Check whether all the required div tags are appearing or not?
- Check whether all div tags are as per the sequence defined in the sample code or not?
- Check whether class attribute has either IIII or 22222 value only

I really appreciate your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would disappointing for you to know that only one requirement among 3 is possible to achieve! I will try to explain in detail the reason!

`<div id="AAA"> // (Required, maxnumber = 1)`
**How to declare a required element:** Declare element `div` with minOccurs = "1" and maxOccurs = "1" (even if you don't define minOccurs and maxOccurs explicitly default values are 1,1. So this is optional)

`<div id="CCC">...</div>// (Optional)` 
**How to declare an optional element:** Declare element 'div' with minOccurs="0" that makes its appearance as optional.

**BUT based on attribute value it is not possible to validate the appearance of elements!** Neither it is possible to have a same element under same parent as once required and once optional!

 well one workaround is for example to have single definition with minOccurs = "3" and maxOccurs="10"

```
<xs:element minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="10" name="div" type="div"/>
```

this will force Document to have atleast 3 occurrence of `div` elements and restricts upto maximum of 10! You can make it infinite by setting `maxOccurs="unbounded"`. This way you can verify if minimum number of div elements are present or not!

**Coming back to your questions:**

> 1.Check whether all the required div tags are appearing or not?

I have answered it.

> 2.Check whether all div tags are as per the sequence defined in the
>   sample code or not?

Again this is not possible to achieve with XSD! Having multiple definitions of same element makes it ambiguous!

> 3.Check whether class attribute has either IIII or 22222 value

only this is possible to achieve having a simpleType defined with enumeration list..

example:

```
  <xs:attribute name="class" type="ClassType" use="optional" />
```

this should be outside the element/complexType:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="ClassType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="IIII"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="2222"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```